# How do I send a value with SQL commands in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I use this code:

I want to place the value in the SQL command via the% s operator, but when I reference the change value with% s, the command does not work:

```
s='amiravira.ir'
q1 = "SELECT DISTINCT name_cat FROM all_user WHERE id='%s' "
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute( q1 ,s)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
myresult
```

The value can be found only if I write the SQL command line itself.
This is exactly the end of my project and it's really weird. I do not know why this happens:

```
q1 = "SELECT DISTINCT name_cat FROM all_user WHERE id = 'amiravira.ir'"
mycursor = mydb.cursor ()
mycursor.execute (q1, s)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall ()
myresult
```

I want to know what should I do to send data via SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

The argument(s) for the execute-call must be passed as an iterable (`tuple` or `list`), even if there's only one.

So write instead:

```py
mycursor.execute(q1, (s,))
```

to pass the argument as an one element tuple.

Comment: Also, most of the time you don't need to write `id='%s'` but `id=%s` and the driver will do the magic for you (if it's a string, will put the ' if the flavor of database requires it)

Comment: but I give this error:     # We have a text result set

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'amiravira.ir''' at line 1

Comment: If you are **not** using parameters inside your SQL, you can just call `mycursor.execute (q1)`.